# C++: Can't understand this code

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm, a-star

Here is the website: [link](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/implementation.html).

This is the part that I don't understand:

```
template<typename L>
struct Graph {
  typedef L Location;
  typedef typename vector<Location>::iterator iterator;
  unordered_map<Location, vector<Location> > edges;

  inline const vector<Location>  neighbors(Location id) {
    return edges[id];
  }
};
```

What I don't understand are these lines:

```
typedef typename vector<Location>::iterator iterator;
      unordered_map<Location, vector<Location> > edges;

      inline const vector<Location>  neighbors(Location id) {
        return edges[id];
      }
```

The first line is what I'm most confused about, what does

```
vector<Location>::iterator iterator
```

do? Is it a function? A type? What does the :: do in this line of code?

For the second line, I've searched what unordered_maps are and it seems like Location is the key and vector is the mapped value? Is this right?

Regarding the third and fourth line, inline doesn't have to be there, right? I looked at the wikipedia page but it's too complicated for me to understand right now. Other than the inline, what the heck does the code do? What does neighbors(Location id) do? I think it's the parameter of neighbors but then what is edges[id]? Does it return the mapped value of the key id from the unordered_map edges?

Sorry if this is all wrong, I don't know many algorithms, almost none, in fact and now I'm trying to learn A* for my PAC-MAN game so there's a big knowledge gap, I think.

Comment: You should read a good book about c++.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Also, a good IDE with "Go to definition/declaration" is an essential tool when exploring code

Comment: @MattWang, lazyness to read is not a good reason to ask here. There are also other sources besides books and wikipedia. "C++ iterator" in google brings up very good explanations. (-1)

Comment: Am I the only one to think this question doesn't show enough personal effort ?

Comment: Okay, I did not put enough effort into this question. Because of that, I'll request for this abomination of a question to be deleted because it's terrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef typename vector<Location>::iterator iterator;
```

This defines a new type alias `iterator` which maps to `vector<Location>::iterator`. The typedef itself isn't actually used in this piece of code though.

```
unordered_map<Location, vector<Location> > edges;
```

This defines an `std::unordered_map` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/ `edges` in which `Location` (which is the templated type) is the Key value and an `std::vector` of `Location`s is the mapped value.

> it seems like Location is the key and vector is the mapped value? Is
>   this right?

That's right, `Location` can be accessed by accessing the `first` member of the pair and the vector can be accessed by accessing the `second` member of the pair.

```
 inline const vector<Location>  neighbors(Location id) {
        return edges[id];
      }
```

`inline` tells the compiler that it shouldn't treat the function as as an actual function but it should replace the code in the function body with the calling code:

```
Graph<int> graph;
auto result = graph.neighbors(5);
```

With inlining this code would translate to:

```
Graph<int> graph;
auto result = graph.edges[id];
```

Note that `inline` is just a hint, the compiler doesn't actually have to listen to it.

Comment: This is a pretty complete answer.

Comment: `inline` is actually completely superfluous here, because the function is implicitly `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
typedef typename vector<Location>::iterator iterator;
```

defines a type alias within the Graph template.  It has this general form:

```
typedef X Y;
```

which makes Y an alias for type X. In this case X is

```
typename vector<Location>::iterator
```

which has the form

```
typename A::B
```

Which means the type B within the class A.  The `typename` keyword is required in this case because `vector<Location>` is dependent on a template parameter.

The end result is that the type `iterator` within `Graph<L>` is an alias for the type `iterator` within `vector<L>`.